# xslt Date related functions

Tags: date, xslt

I want to display the total amount spilttup for each day. I tried with below code .**functx:next-day** function is  used for setting the date filed.
                                                                                                                               Input
   StartDate="04-12-2017"

NoDays = 6

Price=15540

But i want to show the result as shown below. Is there any other function is requird to set the date field value.

```
Current output:


                   <Night>
                        <Price Amount="2590" NightDate="2017-12-05" />
                        <Price Amount="2590" NightDate="2017-12-06" />
                        <Price Amount="2590" NightDate="2017-12-07" />
                        <Price Amount="2590" NightDate="2017-12-08" />
                        <Price Amount="2590" NightDate="2017-12-09" />
                        <Price Amount="2590" NightDate="2017-12-10" />
                    </Night>




Expected Output:

                     <Night>
                        <Price Amount="2590" NightDate="2017-12-04" />
                        <Price Amount="2590" NightDate="2017-12-05" />
                        <Price Amount="2590" NightDate="2017-12-06" />
                        <Price Amount="2590" NightDate="2017-12-07" />
                        <Price Amount="2590" NightDate="2017-12-08" />
                        <Price Amount="2590" NightDate="2017-12-09" />
                    </Night> 



Currently used Logic:

 <Night>                                                                                                
     <xsl:for-each select="1 to $NoDays">

       <Price>                                                                                                                

           <xsl:attribute name="Amount">

              <xsl:value-of select="$Price div $NoDays"/>

         </xsl:attribute>

          <xsl:attribute name="NightDate">

            <xsl:value-of select="functx:next-
                     day(xs:date($StartDate),position())"/>

        </xsl:attribute>

    </Price>

 </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply want

```
    <xsl:variable name="NoDays" select="6"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Price" select="15540"/>
    <xsl:variable name="StartDate">04-12-2017</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="date" as="xs:date" 
                  select="xs:date(replace($StartDate, 
                                          '([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})', 
                                          '$3-$2-$1'))"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="0 to $NoDays - 1">
        <Price Amount="{$Price div $NoDays}" 
               NightDate="{$date + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') * .}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

which exploits that you can multiply a duration with an integer and add it to a date.

Online sample at http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKT

Comment: Excellent solution, almost better than the formulation of the question deserves.